# Native NodeJS MongoDB driver returns different result than direct query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a Node/Express backend using the native mongodb driver to handle data.  I have the following function that extracts data from my mongodb database:

```
else if (year && grouping == 2){
              collection.aggregate([
                { $match: {postdate: { $gte : new Date(yearstart), $lte : new Date(yearend)},factor:1 }},
                { $group: { _id: {"category":"$category","month":{ "$month": "$postdate" }} , "total": { $sum: "$debit" } } },
                { $project: { "_id":0, "category":"$_id.category", "month":"$_id.month", "total":1 } }
              ]
              ).toArray(function(err, items) {
                    console.log("get transactions by year and month category grouping result:  ", items);
                    res.json(GroupByMonthCat(items));
        }
```

The value of yearstart is: '2018-01-01' and the value of yearend is '2018-12-01'.  So in my query I am grouping the matched records on the month part of postdate.

However, the result I get is the following for (category: Bills and month:1):

```
{
    "subtotal" : 475,
    "category" : "Bills",
    "month" : 1
}
```

When I run the same query outside my app directly against my mongodb:

```
db.transtest.aggregate(
    [
     { $match: {category: "Bills" ,postdate: { $gte : new Date("2018-01-01"), $lte : new Date("2018-01-31")},factor:1 }},
     { $group: { _id: {"category":"$category","month":{ "$month": "$postdate" }} , "subtotal": { $sum: "$debit" } } },
     { $project: { "_id":0, "category":"$_id.category", "month":"$_id.month", "subtotal":1} },
     { $sort : { category : -1, month: 1 } }
    ]
);
```

I get the following result:

```
{
    "subtotal" : 183.9,
    "category" : "Bills",
    "month" : 1
}
```

Why would this be happening?  There are only two results in my database for the month of January 2018, hence my expected subtotal of 183.9 as shown when I run the same exact query directly against my database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7641b0d4b6828ad37c99a1"),
    "transid" : 5500,
    "postdate" : ISODate("2018-01-16T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "Bills",
    "debit" : 53.9
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7641b0d4b6828ad37c99a5"),
    "transid" : 5504,
    "postdate" : ISODate("2018-01-25T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "Bills",
    "debit" : 130
}
```

Comment: Your two `$match` terms are different.

Comment: That doesn't matter.  I simply added the category:Bills to isolate my return to the category that is showing the mismatch.

Comment: There's also the `factor:1` term. Anyway, something relevant is clearly different somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I've made an edit to add the factor to my query directly outside the function.  It doesn't change the results.

Comment: I think I've figured out what the problem is.  It has something to do with taking the month datepart in mongodb to group my categories on.  I have a data point that occurs on January 31st and that is not showing.  I can figure it out now.